# llvm.pow.f64 implementation

Tags: llvm

I am unable to find the implementation of llvm.pow.f64 function. I want to see how it is implemented internally. Please let me know whether I can view it's source code or if only it's binary is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SimplifyLibCalls` pass replaces this intrinsic with other calls. Take a look at `PowOpt` in `lib/Transforms/Scalar/SimplifyLibCalls.cpp`.

SimplifyLibCalls::InitOptimizations assigns the call optimizers to intrinsics, and does this for the `llvm.pow.*` ones:

```
  Optimizations["llvm.pow.f32"] = &Pow;
  Optimizations["llvm.pow.f64"] = &Pow;
  Optimizations["llvm.pow.f80"] = &Pow;
  Optimizations["llvm.pow.f128"] = &Pow;
  Optimizations["llvm.pow.ppcf128"] = &Pow;
```